# Linux: Connect Seiko usb printer as serial port

Tags: linux, printing, serial-port, usb

I have a Seiko DPU-D2 printer. I'm connecting it to computer with usb port and I'm trying to write to it using serial. What I don't know is where this printer is mounted.

What I have so far are those pieces of information:

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0619:0115 Seiko Instruments, Inc.

# dmesg
[ 4173.272074] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[ 4173.366653] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0619, idProduct=0115
[ 4173.366665] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4173.366672] usb 2-1.2: Product: SII LTPDx45 Series.
[ 4173.366677] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Seiko Instruments Inc.
[ 4173.368663] usblp 2-1.2:1.0: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 10 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x0619 pid 0x0115
```

Is there some other way to find out where is this printer mounted? Or, if it is not mounted yet, how to mount it and use write to it via serial port in this way `echo "Something" > /dev/tty***`?

Comment: Filesystems are mounted.  Devices are installed (or registered with its upper-layer, e.g. USB), not mounted.  The device cannot be installed if there is no driver for it.

Comment: In dmesg it seems like the driver for this is in usblp module, isn't it?

Comment: I would expect to see a few more log messages if the device was actually installed.  Specifically a successful USB device installation would have a message of the form *"usbcore: registered new interface driver ..."*.

Comment: So there is no way to make it work without some external driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the impression the printer is actually installed correctly. `usblp2` is the device ID. You should be able to print to the printer, but, as `usblp2` is not probably not the standard device, you might have to program the print service (probably `cups`) to use that device to print.

Did you check if usblp2 appears in the printers dialog of cups, when you do 'add new printer' (in `administratation`)? (You'll probably have to authenticate as administrator)

Note that the printer is not listening to serial commands - it's simulating a parallel port. You can probably print simple things by copying directly to it:  `cat <some_text> > /dev/usblp2`

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it print. I didn't use cups because I wanted a low-level service. You were right, the usblp what the right direction, but there was no `usblp2` node in /dev/ folder, which got me confused back then. But now I found a `/dev/usb/lp2` node which worked just fine. The only thing that is weird for me is the parallel port - in the manual there are serial port settings given.

Comment: Maybe the printer also has a physical serial port? Does it have a DB-9 connector? Or maybe the manual is common for two models (or variants, or options) of the same printer? I notice that the spec sheet says Serial/USB, which would mean it does have two connectors (for the -00 model). Please, if the answer was correct, click the 'V' left of the answer, so others can find it more easily!

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I accepted the answer, but now I see that I only gave it a point ;) And indeed the serial interface specification might be for the physical connector (26 pin). Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! I couldn't find a picture of the connector side of the printer - is that really a 26-pin connector for the serial port? Or 25-pin (DB-25)?

Comment: It is a symmetrical 26 pin port. According to manual it's XG4A-2632 (OMRON) connector. Four pins are used to supply power.

Comment: Thanks for the info! If the printer is powered over the flat cable connector, that explains why several pins are necessary for power.